# Failed validation of a named resource form has "Missing template" error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a `grant_requests` controller and I want all all of the actions to show up as "sponsored_licences" in the url.

My routes file has the following:

`resources :sponsored_licences, as: :grant_requests, controller: :grant_requests`

Going to `new_grant_request_path` works as expected; it routes to the `sponsored_licenses/new` url when the form is valid it posts correctly to the database.

However, when there are form validation errors and I `render new_grant_request_path` in the controller I get the `Missing template` error.

Redirecting will not work (I want to save the form data, etc.) and I am at a loss on how to correctly render the form. Is there something else I have to add to my routes file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `render :new` if you're in the GrantRequests controller, otherwise, `render "grant_requests/new"`